# How to define a non-ordinal enum in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums

I want to define an enum that values are not ordinal, for example:

```
enum class States(value: Int) {
    STATE_A(4),
    STATE_B(5),
    STATE_C(7),
    STATE_D(12)
}
```

How can I get the value of each item? For instance **States.STATE_C** should return **7**.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You should define `value` as property (`val`) not as constructor parameter. After that it becomes accessible:

```
enum class States(val value: Int) {
    STATE_A(1),
    STATE_B(2),
    STATE_C(3),
    STATE_D(4)
}
...
println(States.STATE_C.value) // prints 3
```

Also consider to use `ordinal`, which may be suitable in your case:

```
enum class States {
    STATE_A,
    STATE_B,
    STATE_C,
    STATE_D
}
...
println(States.STATE_C.ordinal + 1) // prints 3
```

If you go with that approach, be careful - any change of `States` order can break your code.

Comment: Hi @hluhovskyi, so, technically would the ordinal index will be based on 1?

Comment: Enum's ordinal is **zero** based: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/ordinal.html